# Close command window with java or command line

Tags: java, servlets, command-line

I have the following problem:

I run a

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

line with the following command:

```
 cmd /c db2cwadmin db2 -tv list database directory
```

and the command is executed fine but here is the problem I want to close that window afterwards. The /c closes the initial cmd window but the db2cwadmin stays open. I tried to use && exit but that just closes the first window too.

How can I close the second window?

Thanks.

Viking

P.S. I fingured out that running taskkill /F /FI \"WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:*\" would kill the window but I need to run the cmd window as admin... so hwo can I do that?
When I just run db2cwadmin without the cmd /c it is the same. So what I need would be a cmd as admin window called from the servlet.

Comment: Is `db2cwadmin` a command line tool or a GUI one?

Comment: it's the admin version of db2cmd